# AWS Cognito combined with Android Account Manager for multiple accounts

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, accountmanager

I'd like to show the user of my app a selection of accounts to use (enabling a shared device e.g. for one department, but still being able to identify users).
User identification and authorization works via AWS Cognito User Pool -> federated Identities -> STS.

My problem is, I can't seem to get the AWS SDK to nicely integrate with the Android Account Manager (that I'd also like to use with the SyncManager).

So here's my current approach:

I've tried to separate user authentication from api calls. User authentication was supposed to happen through AccountManager and once it provides an AuthToken the credentialsProvider in CloudService (bound to MainActivity) is configured and api calls become possible. In an attempt to make more use of the AWS Cognito SDK I've created a singleton to hold the UserPool, the current user and the session, but without a real effect.

So far what this solution get me is, I can log in and use the app for a while. After 1h the access token that I stored in AccountManager is expired and I have no direct way of refreshing it. The only way I have been able to refresh the tokens was by not using the AccountManager, since the AWS CachedCredentialsProvider takes care of token refresh. However, this is based on using sharedPreferences and I no visibility to who the currently cached user is, so it's not feasible to go with that.

Long story short, I've tried to put all the significant code below. I hope you can point me in the right direction. Probably I'm already far off architecturally...
Thanks in advance!

**AccountSelectionActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_selection);

    List<Account> availableAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new AccountsViewAdapter(availableAccounts, this);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvAccountsList);
    if (null != recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(
            new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "no RecyclerView found");
    }

    accountManager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
    loadAvailableAccounts();
}

void loadAvailableAccounts(){
    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(
        getString(R.string.account_type));
    if (0 == accounts.length) {
        addAccount(null);
    } else {
        mAdapter.setAccountsList(accounts);
    }
}

// called upon account selection
public void onClick(Account account) {
    selectedAccount = account;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, selectedAccount);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        mAccount = bundle.getParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        if (mAccount == null) {
            finishDueToMissingAccount();
        }
    } else {
        finishDueToMissingAccount();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buddy);
    [...]
}

// called from base class after binding the CloudService
void onCloudServiceConnected() {
    if (mAccount != null ) {
        cloudService.logIn(mAccount, this);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "mAccount = " + mAccount.toString());
    }
}
```

**CloudService**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    accountManager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
    credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
        this, // context
        IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
        IDENTITY_POOL_REGION);
    syncManager = new CognitoSyncManager(
        this, // context
        IDENTITY_POOL_REGION,
        credentialsProvider);
}

[...]

public void logIn(Account account, Activity activity) {
    this.account = account;
    accountManager.getAuthToken(account,
        "n/a", // token type
        null, // options
        activity,
        new OnTokenAcquired(), // callback
        null // handler
    );
}

private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
        try {
            Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<>();
            String token = result.getResult().getString(
                AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
            logins.put(USER_POOL_ARN, token);
            credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: Handle Exception
        } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
            // TODO: Handle Operation Canceled
        } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
            // TODO: Hanlde Authenticator exception
        }
    }
}
```

**Authenticator**

```
@Override
public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
             String accountType, String authTokenType,
             String[] requiredFeatures,
             Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    return promptToLogin(response, options);
}

private Bundle promptToLogin(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Bundle options) {
    options = (options == null) ? new Bundle() : options;
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, AuthenticatorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
    intent.putExtras(options);

    final Bundle result = new Bundle();
    result.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
    return result;
}

public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account,
    String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    Bundle result = new Bundle();
    if (accountExists(account.type)) {
        String token = accountManager.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);
        if ( token != null ) {
            return passBackCurrentAuthToken(account.name, authTokenType,
                result, token);
        }
    }

    return promptToLogin(response, options);
}

private Bundle passBackCurrentAuthToken(String accountName, String authTokenType, Bundle bundle, String token) {
    bundle.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
    bundle.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, authTokenType);
    bundle.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, token);
    return bundle;
}
```

**AuthenticatorActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_authenticator);

    curSession = SessionSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    etMail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMail);
    etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);

}

public void attemptLogin(View v) {
    showWaitDialog("Signing in...");
    curSession.getSessionInBackground(etMail.getText().toString(), authHandler);
}

AuthenticationHandler authHandler = new AuthenticationHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession cognitoUserSession,
                              CognitoDevice cognitoDevice) {
            Bundle result = new Bundle();

            closeWaitDialog();
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "> authHandler > onSuccess");
                curSession.setSession(cognitoUserSession);

                String token = curSession.getIdToken();
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, token);

                AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
                Account account = new Account(etMail.getText().toString(),
                                  getString(R.string.account_type));
                accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, token, result);
                accountManager.setAuthToken(account, "n/a", token);

                setAccountAuthenticatorResult(result);
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                showDialogMessage("ERROR", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String username) {
            String password = etPass.getText().toString();
            AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(username, password, null);
            authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails);
            authenticationContinuation.continueTask();
        }

        @Override
        public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation) {
            closeWaitDialog();
            showDialogMessage("MFA is not supported", "");
        }

        @Override
        public void authenticationChallenge(final ChallengeContinuation continuation) {
            continuation.continueTask();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            closeWaitDialog();
            showDialogMessage("Sign-in failed", formatException(e));
        }
    };
```

**SessionSingleton**

```
private SessionSingleton(Context context) {
    userPool = new CognitoUserPool(
        context,
        USER_POOL_ID,
        CLIENT_ID,
        CLIENT_SECRET,
        new ClientConfiguration(),
        USER_POOL_REGION);
}

void getSessionInBackground(String username, AuthenticationHandler authHandler) {
    user = userPool.getUser(username);
    user.getSessionInBackground(authHandler);
}

void setSession(CognitoUserSession session) {
    this.session = session;
}

CognitoUserSession getSession() {
    return session;
}

String getIdToken() {
    return session.getIdToken().getJWTToken();
}
```